# Basic example is not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, typeahead.js

What's wrong with this code, the basic example if not working. all of the files are in one folder so the path is not the problem, but still this code is not working, how this will work with Web ApI ..?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>   
    <link href="examples.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('input#search-box').typeahead({
  name: 'name',
  local: ['yasser', 'shyam', 'sujesh', 'siddhesh', 'vaibhav']
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>        
    <input type="textbox" placeholder="Search Song" id="search-box" class="typeahead" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) for demonstration purposes, dumping code which can't easily be run due to external resource dependencies isn't going to get you anywhere. Also, as a starter for 10 always start by looking at the web console for scripting errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like for the very basic example you need to bind a method to the source

http://jsfiddle.net/f9DFC/

```
$('input#search-box').typeahead(
  {
    minLength: 1,
  },
  {
    name: 'name',
    displayKey: 'value',
    //This needs to me a function, not an array.
    source: substringMatcher( ['yasser', 'shyam', 'sujesh', 'siddhesh', 'vaibhav'])
  });
```